# Search on the hash code in Sphinx

Tags: search, sphinx, hashcode

I have in the database has a hash code of this type: **b67583fad7ccc238a34eacfcdc16bfd8557cc82f**
They are all 40 characters.
From the database I get ids so:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE info_hash=UNHEX('b67583fad7ccc238a34eacfcdc16bfd8557cc82f')
```

SELECT from MySql whitout UNHEX() don't work. So I use UNHEX().

From Sphinx I tried so:

```
$cl->SetFilter('info_hash',array('UNHEX("b67583fad7ccc238a34eacfcdc16bfd8557cc82f")'));
```

and so

```
$cl->SetFilter('info_hash',array('HEX(UNHEX("b67583fad7ccc238a34eacfcdc16bfd8557cc82f"))'));
```

and even so

```
$result = $cl->Query('@info_hash "'.bin2hex("b67583fad7ccc238a34eacfcdc16bfd8557cc82f").'"',$index_name);
```

Config of Sphinx:

```
sql_query = SELECT id,info_hash,name,cast FROM table_name
sql_field_string = name
sql_field_string = info_hash
sql_field_string = cast
```

For the field cast I get ids so:

```
$result = $cl->Query('@cast "Brad Pitt"',$index_name);
```

And everything works but for info_hash no. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the data stored in the database? `WHERE info_hash=UNHEX('b67583fad7ccc238a34eacfcdc16bfd8557cc82f')` suggests the column actully stores the raw unencoded text (ie about 20 bytes). Or is it actully stored in hex format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $cl->SetFilter('info_hash',array('UNHEX("b67583fad7ccc238a34eacfcdc16bfd8557cc82f")'));

Doesnt work because setFilter takes an array of integers. Plus its not clear who you think will execute the 'UNHEX' function, remember its a mysql function!

---

**php** does have a `hex2bin` function (equiv of `UNHEX()`), so could perhaps use that.

As you've put the hash in a string attribute, could perhap use

```
$cl->SetFilterString('info_hash',hex2bin("b67583fad7ccc238a34eacfcdc16bfd8557cc82f"));
```

Do make sure you set the collection correctly, so that your `binary` string gets preseved propelly. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#collations

(You have it a field as well, but will be hard to match against, as it works with charset_table tokenization so your encoded binary string is unlikely to survive into proper tokens)

Comment: familiar only second day with a Sphinx. I didn't even know about the SetFilterString function =) Thanks you.